# Profiling Delphi OS X application

Tags: macos, delphi, profiling, dwarf

I have a performance critical application for OS X built with Delphi and I would like to profile it to see if there are any bottlenecks I can optimize.

However if I use XCode profiler then it cannot load the debug symbols generated by Delphi and therefore not display any useful information about my program.

Is there any other profiler tool for OS X that can read Delphi symbols?

Or is there a way to convert Delphi debug info (perhaps from .map-file) into a format XCode profiler can use? It seems XCode profiler expects DWARF format.

Comment: Delphi OSX compiler uses the same LLVM backend and debug information as Xcode. See https://www.tmssoftware.com/site/blog.asp?post=288 for an example with iOS, but should work for OSX as well.

Comment: @LURD That's incorrect, Delphi OSX compiler does not use the LLVM backend. I'm not sure what it is based on but wouldn't surprise me if there are traces of the old Kylix compiler in it. So that link you posted won't work.

Comment: The OSX compiler is pretty close to dcc32 and dcc64.  Same front end I believe.  Codegen will be similar to dcc32. OSX doesn't require position independent code, and I'm not sure that dccosx emits it. I'd be surprised if it did. I suspect that the compiler is very close to dcc32, and the debug information likewise. Your best option will be to find a tool to convert the debug info into a format that DWARF can read, but I doubt you'll have much success there. This has long been a headache on the Windows platform too, that Delphi spits out debug info that only Delphi specific tools can use.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Ok, thanks I'll see if I can find more info about dwarf format. Dccosx codegen is very similar to dcc32 so I think you are right. However it does generates PIC code (and there is no way to turn it off, even though there is a compiler setting it has no effect). PIC code is a problem when trying to write crossplatform asm, see this link: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Differences_between_Windows_and_Mac_OS_X#Accessing_Global_Variables_in_ASM_on_Windows_and_OS_X